# Eventos em Elementos Renderizados pela Diretiva v-html no Vue.js

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, eventos, onclick

Como faço para usar um evento em um elemento renderizado pela diretiva v-html? Pelos eventos vue (@evento) não funciona.. Tentei chamar uma função pelo onclick, mas ela não é encontrada.

```
 <button onclick="test()" class="botao">Adicionar ao carrinho</button> // NÃO FUNCIONA

<button onclick="console.log('Clicado')" class="botao">Adicionar ao carrinho</button>  //FUNCIONA
```

Os códigos acima estão sendo renderizados por v-html como no exemplo abaixo:

```
<div v-html="<button onclick="test()" class="botao">Adicionar ao Carrinho</button>">

</div>
```